# ADB Devices not showing my device in Windows 7

Tags: android, android-studio, adb, usb-debugging

I have been dealing with this problem for hours, tried everything, re-installed android-studio & ADB, and nothing. I have also turned on USB Debugging, set the phone connection to data transfer.

set the `ANDROID_HOME` user variable to `android/sdk/platform-tools`.

set the `path` to ADB inside the Android Studio.

I don't know what else to do. Is windows 7 the problem?

Comment: First recheck the device if adb is enabled. Then on Windows check the Windows device manager what devices for the connected phone are visible and if they have. Switch the device manager to "View by connection" mode to see what device(s) belong to your phone.

Comment: I am doing the same in windows 10 and windows 7. In the win 7 pc doesn't work but in win 10 does. I have check that and yeah usb debugging is enabled and I can see my phone files through file explorer, but still not showing in adb devices